# Catch block not execting in C++ program

Tags: try-catch

I am running a c++ program with a catch block for all exceptions under Snow Leapard. The program is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int DefaultSize = 10;

int main()
{
   int top = 90;
   int bottom = 0;

   try
   {
      cout << "top / 2 = " << (top/ 2) << endl;

      cout << "top divided by bottom = ";
      cout << (top / bottom) << endl;

      cout << "top / 3 = " << (top/ 3) << endl;
   }
   catch(...)
   {
      cout << "something has gone wrong!" << endl;
   }

   cout << "Done." << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I am using g++ version i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1 to compile the program: g++ -o test test.cpp.  The catch block is not executing. The output is: "top / 2 = 45
Floating point exception". No error message or Done is printed. The output is exactly the same as when the try-catch block is not present. Can someone tell me why the catch is not executing? I have gotten user-defined exceptions to work.

Answer (score 0):

there is no default zero divide error in c++. So, you need to check if the bottom value is 0

```
try{
    if(bottom==0)
         throw bottom; //Or any integer
   }

catch(int x)
{
     cout<<"Something has gone wrong";
}
```